# How can i check my input after each iteration on Luis?

Tags: node.js, chatbot, azure-language-understanding

```
if (!meeting.location) {
     builder.Prompts.text(session, 'where is the location');
} else {
     next();
}
```

This is a part of my node.js code where my bot tries to identify the location in the first message , if he doesn't find it he takes as location any value the user gives, might be as random as "83748yhgsdh".

My question is how can i allow my system to check the user input at each step and only take reasonable ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably manually call the `LUIS` recognizer

e.g:

```
var recognizer = new builder.LuisRecognizer(model);
recognizer.recognize(
  "hello",
   model,
  function (err, intents, entities) {
    console.log(intents);
  }
)
```

Comment: Hello, can you kindly explain as i don't understand how that code will check the user's input, and make sure it's a valid one in the correspondent entity, and adjusting it to my example above would be helpful.

Comment: You want to send a the location entered by the user to LUIS again to see if detects a location or what do you want to do?